# C++ define and initialize array of struct instances: Undefined Variable?

Tags: c++11

Question if C++11 supports initializing an array, so not a stl container, with an initializer list of structs that contain again an C++ type like std::string. See code below.

Compiler I'm using does NOT complain:gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)

Code seems to run perfect.

Valgrind does not complain.

But the static analyzer tool we are evaluating does complain:

const MyStruct02 myArr02[] = {
                {"Value 0",   0,         -1,    41943040},

- **Uninitialized Variable**
- myArr02 was not initialized.
- myArr02 was defined at Repro001_Unitialized_Variable.cpp:49.

The analyzer is referring to: http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/457.html

Code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct MyStruct01
{
    const char* description;
    int         val1;
    int         val2;
    int         val3;
};

struct MyStruct02
{
    std::string description;
    int         val1;
    int         val2;
    int         val3;
};

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    const MyStruct01 myArr01[] = {
        {"Value 0",   0,         -1,    41943040},
        {"Value 1",   10,   5000000,    10485760},
        {"Value 2",   20,   1000000,    409600  },
        {"Value 3",   30,    500000,    204800  },
        {"Value 4_0", 40,    200000,    102400  }
    };

    std::cout << myArr01[0].description << std::endl;


    const MyStruct02 myArr02[] = {
        {"Value 0",   0,         -1,    41943040},
        {"Value 1",   10,   5000000,    10485760},
        {"Value 2",   20,   1000000,    409600  },
        {"Value 3",   30,    500000,    204800  },
        {"Value 4_0", 40,    200000,    102400  }
    };

    std::cout << myArr02[0].description << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

After some puzzling I found out that replacing the std::string in the struct by a native "const char*" removes the Uninitialized Variable warning.

So my question: Is the static analyzer tool right or is it wrong???

Thanks for any help.

Henry

Comment: What analyzer did you use exactly? Does GCC warn you with `-pedantic -Wall`?

Comment: @usr1234567 Analyzer=CodeSonar. g++ -pedantic -Wall ... -> does not return any warnings. Thanks for help

Comment: I believe the code is right, the compiler is right, and the analyzer is wrong.

Comment: @HenryRoeland You can try Clang and Its static analyzer. Beside that, I don't see a problem.